# Can I exchange a UK for a DE license when my UK license is not yet about to expire?

Tags: germany, eu, driving-license, brexit

I have a UK driving license that is valid until 2027.  The license indicates that I originally passed my test in The Netherlands.  Normally, EU licenses are not exchanged before they expire ([source](https://www.kreis-offenbach.de/B%C3%BCrgerservice/Fahrerlaubnis-ausl%C3%A4ndisch-EU-EWR-Staaten-umschreiben.php?object=tx,2896.2&ModID=10&FID=1856.89.1)).  However, I would like to exchange my UK license now, because I am worried that Brexit may complicate the bureaucracy involved.  Is such an exchange possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  The advice from UK government is that holders of UK driving licenses who live in Germany should exchange their driving licenses before 29th March

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-germany#driving-in-germany

Linked from there is advice from the German government:

https://www.bmvi.de/SharedDocs/EN/Documents/LA/fact-sheet-foreign-driving-licences.pdf?__blob=publicationFile

Section 2.4 of that document says:

> Even without a special reason, you may exchange your valid foreign driving
>   licence for a German driving licence at any time.

Comment: I tried to exchange my license this morning, but the application was refused — they only consider license exchange when people have been at least four months in the country, and I've been less than two.  So I cannot follow the advice from the UK government, and the "at any time" from the BMVI document is incorrect.  The person at the Landkreis office thought there would probably be a solution for UK licenses after Brexit.  We shall see.

Comment: @gerrit - that's terrible luck.  (There is still quite a chance that Brexit will be delayed at least a few weeks, which may be enough to get you over the four month mark.)

Comment: Turns out that Brexit is delayed well past my four month mark.  Looks like the linked page wisely no longer mentions any date, just "before the UK leaves the EU".

Answer (score 0):

When I moved to live in Germany, I had to change my Latvians (EU) drivers licence and get German drivers licence. Even if both countries are in EU and my drivers licences due time was in 8 years. I guess it is related to speed and parking tickets, and penalty points.

Exchange procedure was extremely simple - eye test and first aid training.

So if you live in Germany - get German drivers licence.

Comment: Why did you have to exchange it? My Dutch license I did not have to exchange in Sweden.

Comment: @gerrit maybe I should start that it was 13 years ago. But it seams still to be correct: https://www.bmvi.de/SharedDocs/EN/Documents/LA/fact-sheet-foreign-driving-licences.pdf  "2.1 -- You must have a domestic driving licence --" I guess it is related to speed and parking tickets, and penalty points.